# How to decrease memory usage in codeeval Road Trip challenge

Tags: python, beginner, programming-challenge, python-2.x, memory-optimization

I'm solving easy CodeEval challenges in Python 2.7. Usually my solutions use around 256 bytes of memory according to CodeEval. With [Road Trip](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/124/) however while time used is still low (30-40ms), memory is >5881866 bytes.  As I'm somewhat of a beginner, is there an easy way to decrease memory usage?

For each test case, which consists of one line of input that lists cities and their locations on a line, the task is to find the incremental distances when visiting them all.  Input follows the template ("city_name", distance;"city_name", distance;):

```
Rkbs,5453; Wdqiz,1245; Rwds,3890; Ujma,5589; Tbzmo,1303;
Vgdfz,70; Mgknxpi,3958; Nsptghk,2626; Wuzp,2559; Jcdwi,3761;
Yvnzjwk,5363; Pkabj,5999; Xznvb,3584; Jfksvx,1240; Inwm,5720;
Ramytdb,2683; Voclqmb,5236;
```

The data set is pretty big for this challenge:

- The route length is an integer in range [10000, 30000]
- The number of cities is in range [500, 600]

My solution is as follows:

```
test_cases = open(file)
for line in test_cases:
    line = line.strip()
    if line == "": continue
    line = line.replace(';', ' ').replace(',', ' ').split()
    distances = sorted(map(int, [line[i] for i in range(1, len(line), 2)]))
    result = [distances[i] - distances[i-1] for i in range(1, len(distances))]
    result.insert(0, distances[0])
    print ','.join(map(str, result))
```

Comment: You probably want to think about some solution that uses [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)... You can start by looking at [this](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/) until someone posts a more detailed answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to preprocess the `line` so much.  `line = line.strip()` duplicates the line, for no benefit.  I don't know why `if line == "": continue` should be needed.  `line = line.replace(';', ' ').replace(',', ' ').split()` degrades the data, and takes two passes to do it.

Here's how I would read the input:

```
for line in fileinput.input():
    route = itertools.chain([0], sorted(
        int(city.group(1)) for city in re.finditer(r'[A-Za-z]+,(\d+);', line)
    ))
```

Using [`fileinput.input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) will let you take input from either a file specified on the command line, or `sys.stdin` if no file is specified.  [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) will look for the pattern and capture the numbers that you need.

In Python 2, you should use `xrange()` instead of `range()`.  However, if you capture just the numbers, as I've done above, then you wouldn't need to use `range()` or `xrange()` to extract every other item.

Each of your list comprehensions results in another temporary copy of the data.  `result.insert(0, distances[0])` is also bad for performance, since every entry must be copied to make room for one entry at the front of the list.

To finish off the solution, I would do this:

```
print(','.join(str(b - a) for a, b in pairwise(route)))
```

… using the [`pairwise()` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from `itertools`.

Comment: I had to read a bit to follow every suggestion you've made. According to codeeval using your methods for getting the distances and building the output, memory usage drops to 2,985,984 bytes - quite an improvement, although I would've expected a value way below 1 MB. Thank you very much for the tips - my experience with re and itertools is almost non-existent, so I have to fix that. Strangely - removing only the list insertion last night had no effect on either memory or space performance, but I understand how it's a bad practice in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to conserve memory is to eliminate the results list and just print the differences directly from distances:

```
    sys.stdout.write(str(distances[0])+',')
    for i in range(1,len(distances)-1):
        sys.stdout.write(str(distances[i] - distances[i-1])+',')
    print(str(distances[i+1] - distances[i]))
```

Comment: Indeed, the large results list appears useless. Your code however need to look like this to work:
`sys.stdout.write(str(dist[0]))
for i in range(1,len(wtf)):
    sys.stdout.write(',' + str(dist[i] - dist[i-1]))
sys.stdout.write('\n')
`
Thanks for introducing me to sys.stdout.write() :)

Comment: @Alaris - Actually both will work equally well.  But, in my example, there is one less operation since print automatically adds '\n'.

Answer (score 1):

The code seems fine, although I'd like to replace cryptic line-parsing line with something more expressive, like:

```
distances = set()
for city_info in line.strip().split(';'):
    if not city_info: continue
    name, distance = city_info.strip().split(',')
    distances.add(distance)
```

Also, you `insert` to the beginning of the list. This is not that fast and can be trivially replaced. Say, last 2 lines of your code could be replaced with something like:

```
print '0,' + ','.join(map(str, result))
```

Or maybe even like:

```
print '0,' + ','.join(str(distance_diff) for distance_diff in result)
```

if 2.7 supports this and if you find comprehensions more comprehensible than `map`s (many people do, but again, many people don't and there is a difference in performance, too).

> is there an easy way to decrease memory usage?

First of all, it'd be nice to know how memory usage is measured. Several programs using around 256 bytes looks a bit suspicious to me, there may be caveats that are not obvious.

Still, ~10 kb to process a pair of city name and an integer looks a bit too much.

If we're talking about simple solutions, that doesn't include looking into how GC (of Python implementation used at CodeEval) works. Let's simply use `del` on every "big" variable after we're done with it: you don't need `line` when you have your `distance`s, and you don't need your distance's when you have your `result`.

Also try calling [gc.collect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) in each iteration.

---

It is *possible* to solve the problem without creating "big" variables like `distance` and `result`. You will need to have an iterator over numbers in the line that does not use *O(n)* memory - let's call it `numbers(line)`. We'll also need following stuff:

```
def low_footprint_sort(numbers):
    smallest_number_limit = 0;
    while True:
        candidate = float('inf')
        for number in numbers():
            if candidate > number > smallest_number_limit:
                candidate = number
        if float('inf') == candidate:
            break
        else:
            yield candidate
            smallest_number_limit = candidate

def neighbour_diffs(numbers):
    previous = next(numbers)
    for number in numbers:
        yield number - previous
        previous = number
```

With that, `neighbour_diffs(low_footprint_sort(lambda: numbers(line)))` would give you numbers you'd have in your `result` without additional *O(n)* memory footprint.

Then you use the same approach - instead of constructing large string via `join`, you print numbers one by one.

That code sacrifices performance and readability for tiny gains in memory consumption (which would only come to play after your lists are big enough - generators have their housekeeping too). You could also try more sophisticated reading from file, that eliminates the need for storing `line` in memory too.

That would result in an overengineered contraption with memory consumption (theoretically) independent of string length and number of strings, yay!

---

**However, that being *possible* certainly does not mean it's a good idea.**

**You should generally find yourself on the other end of these tradeoffs.**

If you were interested in low-hanging fruit - try fiddling with `del`s and `collect()`s. I don't see other obvious solutions that are better.

If you were interested in a bit more challenging ways to curb the memory footprint even if it costs some complexity - well, there are ways too.

Either way, it's only suitable for programming puzzles.